# Why aren't there V-tail airliners?

Tags: aircraft-design, airliner, drag, tail, weight

Since a V-tail is lighter and generates less drag than a conventional empennage, why has this solution been put away from production?

Comment: V-tail design is in production. One of most recent addition is [SF50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirrus_Vision_SF50).

Comment: Related explanation of [V-tail effectiveness in damping](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/9509/3201).

Answer (score 10):

Controllability and redundancy. Airliners are certified according CFR 14 Part 25, which specifies that upon engine fail the aircraft must still be able to fly and climb: it must have more than one engine.

After an engine has failed, the rudder must be deflected in order to compensate for the asymmetric thrust of the remaining engine. With a V-tail, this means that after engine fail, there is less pitch authority: pitch and yaw surface deflections are coupled. A V-tail has two control surfaces that combine aircraft yaw control and pitch control, which goes well until one of the surfaces hits a stop.

[image: https://img.rcgroups.com/http://www.vvsss.com/ezone/v-tail.gif?h=b07Nxx_byxTYTzxk_sDclA]

Reduced pitch control due to an engine failure would be unacceptable for an airliner. For a single engine plane with the engine in the centreline, this yaw trim condition would not happen.

Comment: isn't it roll/yaw coupling?

Comment: @user3528438 roll can be compensated with ailerons, in a v-tail there is not another control surface for compensating for pitch when the yaw control has to compensate for asymmetric thrust.

Comment: @user3528438 What is meant is that on a V-tail, the control surfaces placed there substitute the conventional rudder and elevator and are thus effecting yaw and pitch control combined. On an (asymmetric) engine failure, some - often significant enough to actually dimension the rudder in the first place - yaw control surface deflection is required which would then reduce available pitch deflection due to the same control surfaces being used for both.

Comment: But arent the surfaces enlarged to compensate for double duty?  Ref be33/36 vs v35.

Comment: @acpilot Yes they can be, however there are practical limits: enlarge them enough and the advantage of smaller tail surfaces is gone. Engine fail means lower speed, higher required elevator & rudder deflections etc. All works out OK for centreline single engines - except for the [fishtailing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/9524/21091) that is reported.